# Help to improve this javascript input mask

Tags: javascript, regex, events, input, mask

Features

- Only numbers
- A unique dot (.)

But...i need improve to **allow user digits *only two numbers* after the dot**

Valid examples:

- 121213
- 123450.10
- 12345678910111213.39

The current code (adapted from [this](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/029c978b-aac5-472e-97a8-95b256f5febd/How-Can-I-Use-Javascript-to-Allow-Only-Numbers-to-Be-Entered-in-a-TextBox.aspx), *not need to keep exactly the same code...*) :

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
   <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
      <!--
      function isNumberKey(evt,obj){

         var containsDot = obj.value.indexOf(".");

         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
              if(charCode == 46 && containsDot < 0){
                return true;
              }
                return false;
         }
         return true;
      }
      //-->
   </SCRIPT>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <INPUT id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this)" type="text" name="txtChar">
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted a fully working version of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/georgecalm/NRtVs/2/

HTML:

```
<input id="txt" type="text" name="txtChar" />
```

JS:

```
var isStrValid = function(str) {
  return ((str.match(/[^\d^.]/) === null) 
       && (str.replace(/\d+\.?\d?\d?/, "") === ""));
};

var node = dojo.byId("txt");
dojo.connect(node, "onkeyup", function() {
    if (!isStrValid(node.value)) {
      node.value = node.value.substring(0, node.value.length-1);
    }
});
```

The first checks (of the isStrValid) makes sure you don't have anything but numbers and a dot. The second checks the pattern.

Comment: i tried "debugging" your code with alert and returns "false" with 111.1

Comment: @celsowm right. You asked to "allow only two numbers after the dot". So that's what the regex above expects. "111.1" has only one number after the dot. Do you want: at most two, but min one number after the dot?

Comment: but actually using your code inside "keypress", the user cannot digits 111.11

Comment: @celsowm I think that depends on how you implement it. If this is a validator, then it should complain on all bad cases. (Take a look at the updated answer).

Comment: red and black is cool too ! But i need a 'mask', preventing the user from typing the wrong things

Answer (score 3):

Just use a regular expression. E.g.

```
function isNumberKey(evt, obj){
    return obj.value.match(/[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?/)
}
```

Comment: I think that will match `99.` and `99.3` , just FYI.

Comment: @rlb.usa That is intentional, otherwise when you try to type a dot your character will not be accepted since false is returned.

@celsown It might need a little tweaking, just look into JavaScript regular expressions.

Comment: His function determines if the next key pressed should be accepted. I don't think that key is in obj.value yet when this occurs, so your code is really saying that adding an extra character (any character) after e.g. 25.67 is ok, since it will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

If it has a dot, but does not have two digits after it, return false.

```
if(containsDot && obj.value.split(".")[1].length != 2){
  return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start off the function with

```
if (obj.value.match(/\.[0-9][0-9]/)) {
    // Already has two decimals
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Yeah, I guess there are some characters that you have to always allow, returning true for them before even doing the above check.